# Grails Spring Security Core Plugin redirect issue

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using the "Spring Security Core Plugin" for Grails and am using a simple map in my Config.groovy file to restrict access based on authentication type.

For example, I want to prevent users from going to the "user/create" page because obviously you wouldn't want people to be able to create other users when they're logged in (I'm ignoring for now that managers/mods would be able to have this functionality). To accomlish this, I have

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    '/user/create':  ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']
 ]
```

The only problem is, it seems to be acting like the action:

```
redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
```

I want it to **redirect to the page it was previously on** though.

i.e.   user/list, attempt to call action create from user controller, if logged in, would reidirect back to user/list.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: If you **don't** want an anonymous user to access the `/user/create` page, don't you mean to use a user role or `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` in the `interceptUrlMap`?

Comment: No, the opposite, I want people who aren't logged in to be able to create an account.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I don't think you can do what you want using `['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']`, it won't restrict logged in user since per documentation

> The token accepts any authentication, even anonymous.

Why not just put something like

```
//in user controller
def create() {
  if(springSecurityService.currentUser) {
    //let them know they're already logged in
    flash.message = message(code: 'your.....message')
    redirect(action: "list")
  }

  //else take them to create form
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also change 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' to 'permitAll'. and use the if statement.